# Windows Socket using C

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I try to open o socket on windows between my 2 computers with windows10 professional and compile it to a C file with codeblock 20.03 IDE.Here is my code

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>

#define BUF_SIZE 500

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sfd;
    char buf[500];
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr, cli;
    int tmp = 0;

    sfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_addr("MyIpAdressOnLocal", &servaddr.sin_addr);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(8000);
    if (connect(sfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr)) != -1)
        0;
    else
        close(sfd);

    while (read(sfd, buf, 500) > 0)
    {
        int (*foo)() = (int(*)())buf;
        tmp = foo();
    }
}
```

I have the folowing error when i try to compile it with codeblock 20.03

```
too many arguments to function 'inet_addr'
```

When `inet_addr` is my local IP adress as `192.168.*.**`.Do i have to use `inet_aton` instead of `inet_addr` ?

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-inet_addr) for proper usage.

Comment: After fixing this compile time error, start testing each return value of the socket functions. Use WSAGetLastError for identifying the problems. At least you need to initialize Winsock for your app. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup

Comment: +1 for the comments to RTFM and test for errors, especially when writing networking code. I would also get in the habit of reading the BSD/Linux documentation (any flavor) for these functions, for two reasons.  First, the ability to read a standard man page is a useful skill that takes time to develop.  Second, the man page text is terse and precise.  It can aid your understanding even though Winsock varies from the Posix API in a few ways.    Once you've read (and understood) the man page, Microsoft's documentation of their function is often easier to understand.

Comment: You will run into problems if you don't initialize the socket library with `WSAStartup`. As mentioned above winsock has a lot of similarities to BSD/Linux sockets, but the requirement to run `WSAStartup` is one of the major differences. Another important difference is that in winsock you need to use `closesocket` instead of `close`.